# How to change color in first td in my table using class

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, css-selectors

I have this table CSS:

```css
table.show-my-request-table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    border-collapse: collapse; 
}
tr.show-my-request-table-header{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
tr.show-my-request-table{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
tr.show-my-request-table:hover{
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
```

And table HTML:

```
<table class="show-my-request-table center">
    <tr class="show-my-request-table-header">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Priority</th> 
        <th>Question</th>
    </tr>
    <tr  >
        <td class="show-my-request-table">                                11.8.2016 15:27:13
        </td>
        <td>  
            <img src="/resources/img/priority-flag/priority-LOW-icon.png" class="priority-icon">
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr  >
        <td class="show-my-request-table">
            11.8.2016 14:45:41
        </td>
        <td>  
            <img src="/resources/img/priority-flag/priority-LOW-icon.png" class="priority-icon">
        </td>
        <td>
            Jak se máš?
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want set up a red background for the first `td` tag.

My problem is, that I don't know how to do it for only one table.

When I try:

```css
td:first-child {
    background-color: #ff0000; 
}
```

it works for all tables.

I think that this code is good, but not working:

```css
table.show-my-request-table > td:first-child {
    background-color: #ff0000; 
}
```

Why? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
table.show-my-request-table tr > td:first-child {
    background-color: #ff0000; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `>` (immediate children selector) just put a `space`

Try this:

```
table.show-my-request-table td:first-child {
    background-color: #ff0000; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/* grab 2nd row, then color the first cell */
tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

## See it in action below

```css
table.show-my-request-table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr.show-my-request-table-header {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tr.show-my-request-table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tr.show-my-request-table:hover {
  background-color: #D3D3D3;
}
/* grab 2nd row, then color the first cell */

tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<table class="show-my-request-table center">
  <tr class="show-my-request-table-header">
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Priority</th>
    <th>Question</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="show-my-request-table">

      11.8.2016 15:27:13

    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="/resources/img/priority-flag/priority-LOW-icon.png" class="priority-icon">
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="show-my-request-table">

      11.8.2016 14:45:41

    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="/resources/img/priority-flag/priority-LOW-icon.png" class="priority-icon">
    </td>
    <td>
      Jak se máš?
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> table.show-my-request-table > td:first-child {
>     background-color: #ff0000; 
> }
> ```

This selector tries to target a `td` that is a *direct* child of the `table` element. As your own code shows:

> ```
> <table class="show-my-request-table center">
>     <!-- snip -->
>     <tr  >
>         <td class="show-my-request-table">
> ```

There is (and has to be) a `tr` element between them. But that's not all: the HTML parser will also silently insert a `tbody` element as a parent for the `tr` (unless you have explicitly included a `<thead>` or `<tbody>` tag). The `<tbody>` tag is optional in HTML, but the *element* is not, so the parser will simply add the element if the tag is missing.

The solution is to use the [*descendant* selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#descendant-combinators):

```css
table.show-my-request-table td:first-child {
    background-color: #ff0000; 
}
```

A keen observer will notice that the `>` combinator has been replaced by a   (space) combinator.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to target the element inside the table

Try this

```
table.show-my-request-table tr td:first-child {
    background-color: #ff0000; 
}
```

Here's a code pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkrmqK

Cheers and happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
table.show-my-request-table > td:nth-child(1) {
    background: #25a3c2; 
}
```